# node-RED json object - how to extract json values

Tags: node-red

In node-RED, I used 'batcher' node to bring 2 Humidity readings together in a msg, which I want in a json format, to use it downstream, one for inside, there other in a quad.

The constructed msg object now looks like this:

```
{ "topic": "Hum", "payload": [ { "inside": 29 }, { "quad": 54 } ] }
```

I am trying to get to elements in this object, with:

```
msg.payload.inside
```

But it is not working, how can I get to for instance the inside humidity ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `payload` property of that object is an Array that contains two elements.

If you want to access the value of an object inside that array, you need to index into it.

Arrays are indexed from `0` - so you want to use `msg.payload[0].inside`

Note that this is standard JavaScript and not specific to Node-RED.

Comment: Thank you! Did not know I will catch you on this side, dis not want to post on the NR google group, as I knew this was not a NR pronlem, thanks again!